# Intermittent PC POST - what else to check

Tags: boot, post

I know there are thousands of questions where a machine won't POST or boot, but I'm experiencing something *slightly* different.

I've got a fairly standard desktop (motherboard with onboard graphics, no cards, processor, 2 sticks of RAM, 2 hard drives, 1 dvd drive - that's it), and for a couple of years worked perfectly.

All of a sudden, it failed to boot.  No POST, no beeps, nothing.

Swapped out motherboard for a brand new one, and put a brand new power supply in there.

Still get the same problem.  However, if I do a hard reset, it someones works fine.

My usual routine is as follows -

1. Power on machine - no POST, no beep, nothing.  Hard drives spin, fans kick off, but nothing beyond that
2. Hold power button down - machine shuts off
3. Power on machine again - POST succeeds, get beep, machine starts to load, then freezes - either during BIOS, or on Windows loading screen, or sometimes a couple of minutes after Windows has completely loaded - can't see a pattern yet
4. Hold power button down - machine shuts off
5. Power on machine - works perfectly

Sometimes it takes a few hard resets to get to step 3, but once step 3 has happened, it is guaranteed to boot fine on the next reset.

I know it's really hard do diagnose these issues without looking at the hardware itself, but what have I missed?

If it's a brand new motherboard and power supply, experiencing exactly the same problem as the other motherboard and power supply, surely that means the motherboard and power supply are fine.

I just can't figure out what could be causing it to fail to boot from cold, if it will ultimately get there.

Could my processor (i3) be on the way out?  Never experienced that before, but I'm running out of guesses!

Oh, and I've tried booting with no peripherals, no drives and no RAM, and get the same problem.  Even with no RAM, it sometimes fails to beep telling me the RAM is missing.  A few hard resets later, and it will.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe some issue with the power and/or reset switches/wiring on the case. Or a failing/dodgy CPU fan causing overheating of the CPU.

Comment: Overheating would not be this quick during cold boot. Intels need time to reach critical temp, so this would be more likely power issue. Or chipset on it's way out. There a lot of peripherals on the MB nowadays. Try to shut down everything in BIOS. Is this a DIY machine or from one of the vendors? If former, MB make/model?

Comment: It's an Asus P9Z77-V LX.  When I first had this issue, I replaced it with a brand new motherboard (same make and model), and experienced the same issue on first boot.  Only things that stayed the same are processor, fan, HD, RAM and case.  Could it really be the wiring in the case that's tripping this out?